# How to expand object to primitive properties using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class StudentTeacher
{
public Student Student {get; set;}   
public Teacher Teacher {get; set;}   
public int OverlappingClasses {get; set;}
}
```

Now, in my code I have a list of objects.

```
List<StudentTeacher> studentTeacher = GetStudentTeachers();
```

Now, I need to select all properties as properties not as objects.

So, for example, I can do this: `studentTeacher.Select(x=>x.Student)` and it will return  a list of objects (IEnumerable).

But when I select multiple properties, i.e. studentTeacher.Select(x=> new {x.Student, x.Teacher}).ToList() the return type is `IEnumerable {Anonymous {Student, Teacher}}`

How, instead of this complex anonymous type I can have a simple anonymous type with properties only.   (So, it will be `Anonymous{StudentID, StudentName, StudentLastName, TeacherID, TeahcerName, TeacherLastName, etc.}`)

One way to do this is by explicitly specifying all properties in the select clause but in my particular use case I have >30 properties in each object and the total # of properties is >100.)

Comment: there might be a way to do this using reflection, i don't know. But are there any properties with the same name in both of these classes?

Comment: You mean you want to flatten the objects into a single anonymous type? So Student.Id would become StudentId, etc? If that's the case, how do you 
plan to handle reference loops?

Comment: Why not creating a DTO and using AutoMapper?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId
        {
            get;
            set;
        } = 1;

        public string StudentName
        {
            get;
            set;
        } = "Name";
    }

    public class Teacher
    {
        public int TeacherId
        {
            get;
            set;
        } = 666;

        public string TeacherName
        {
            get;
            set;
        } = "TeacherName";
    }

    public class StudentTeacher
    {
        public Student Student
        {
            get;
        } = new Student();

        public Teacher Teacher
        {
            get;
        } = new Teacher();
    }

    public static dynamic GetAnonType(Student student, Teacher teacher)
    {
        var propertyNamesAndPropertiesStudent = student.GetType().GetProperties().Select(item => Tuple.Create($"{nameof(Student)}{item.Name}", item.GetMethod.Invoke(student, null)));
        var propertyNamesAndPropertiesTeacher = teacher.GetType().GetProperties().Select(item => Tuple.Create($"{nameof(Teacher)}{item.Name}", item.GetMethod.Invoke(teacher, null)));
        dynamic sampleObject = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach(var propertyNamePropertyValuePair in propertyNamesAndPropertiesStudent)
        {
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)sampleObject).Add(propertyNamePropertyValuePair.Item1, propertyNamePropertyValuePair.Item2);
        }

        foreach(var propertyNamePropertyValuePair in propertyNamesAndPropertiesTeacher)
        {
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)sampleObject).Add(propertyNamePropertyValuePair.Item1, propertyNamePropertyValuePair.Item2);
        }

        return sampleObject;
    }
```

You can call this like this:

```
        var studentTeachers = new List<StudentTeacher> {new StudentTeacher()};
        var anonTypes = studentTeachers.Select(item => GetAnonType(item.Student, item.Teacher));
```

anonTypes will be an enumerable of anonymous types with members StudentId, StudentName, TeacherId, TeacherName. This should scale to larger objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
studentTeacher.Select(x=> new 
{x.Student.StudentID, x.Student.StudentName, x.Student.StudentLastName, x.Teacher.TeacherID, x.Teacher.TeahcerName, x.Teacher.TeacherLastName, etc.})
```

It will use the property name as the name inside the object ie Student = x.Student.StudentID
Also you can assign directly
eg

```
studentTeacher.Select(x=> new 
{ StudentID = x.Student.StudentID, x.Student.StudentName, x.Student.StudentLastName, x.Teacher.TeacherID, x.Teacher.TeahcerName, x.Teacher.TeacherLastName, etc.})
```

Comment: OP mentioned he knows this already and wants to know if it can be done dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of properties, why not select the whole class?

```
IEnumerable<StudentTeacher> studentTeachers = GetStudentTeachers();
IEnumerable<StudentTeacher> femaleTeachers = studentTeachers
    .Where(teacher => teacher.IsFemale);
```

Now you don't have to mention all your properties. This also works with joins:

```
var TeachersWithTheirStudents = studentTeachers.GroupJoin(students,
    teacher => teacher.Id,
    student => student.TeacherId,
    (teacher, students) => new
    {
        Teacher = teacher,
        HisStudents = students,
    }
```

In words: group join the collections of `Teachers` and `Students`. From each `Teacher` take the `Id`. Take all `Students` with a `TeacherId` equal to this `Id`, from this `Teacher` and all his `Students` make one Anonymous object with properties `Teacher` and `HisStudents`