# Get custom object from lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this method:

```
 public static SiteSettingEntity 
       GetSettings<SiteSettingEntity>(string siteId, 
                 Expression<Func<SiteSettingEntity, object>> properties)
 {
     // This method returns a SiteSettingEntity
     // filled with the values  selected in my expression
 }
```

If want to invoke:

```
var _siteSetting = SiteSettingService.GetSettings<SiteSettingEntity>(SiteID, 
                 s => new { s.BillCycleType, s.InvoiceComment, 
                s.AllowInvoiceDetailApproval, s.JobMinimumHours });
```

So this returns an object with the properties filled that was selected by my lambda expression.

My question is: how I do to return a custom object dynamically same using my expression?

Taking an example: when if you want to use `.Select(s => new{ filed1 = data.FieldX})`, you can just use the property `.filed1` in return object.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but it's not really clear what you are trying to do. You want to extract a field value from a lambda expression ?

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874566/how-to-expand-object-to-primitive-properties-using-linq/45876836#45876836)?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to return a dynamic object?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract all properties from expression and return a "custom object" with only these properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to return a dynamic object you can do something like this simple example of using ExpandoObject:

```
public class DuckFactory
{
    public ExpandoObject GetDuck()
    {
        dynamic duck = new ExpandoObject();
        duck.Name = "Fauntleroy";
        return duck;
    }
}
```

And then call it like:

```
dynamic duck = new DuckFactory().GetDuck();

//  Check the property exists before using it
if (((IDictionary<string, Object>)duck).ContainsKey("Name"))
{                
    Console.WriteLine(duck.Name);   //  Prints Fauntleroy
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Poor duck doesn't have a name.");
}
```

Just remember you won't get the benefits of the object being strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

This is my original method:

```
public static T GetSettings<T>(string siteId, Expression<Func<SiteSettingEntity, object>> properties)
    {
        string query = $"SELECT TOP 1 {DbTool.GetSqlFields(properties)} FROM {SiteSettingEntity.TABLE_NAME} (NOLOCK) WHERE Sites.SiteID = @SiteID";

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"SiteID", siteId},
        };

        var _data = DbTool.SqlExec<T>(PowerDetailContext.GetConnectionString(siteId), CommandType.Text, query, parameters);

        return _data != null ? _data.FirstOrDefault() : default(T);
    }
```

Ang the when I made the call I have this:

```
var _siteSetting = SiteSettingService.GetSettings<SiteSettingEntity>(SiteID, s => new { s.BillCycleType, s.InvoiceComment, s.AllowInvoiceDetailApproval, s.JobMinimumHours });
```

the var _siteSetting I want just have the properties SELECTED between new{} when I called. If I try use _siteSetting.**OtherProperty**, the "**OtherProperty**" won't available in the code.

Answer (score 0):

After reading it again I suppose you are just trying to return SiteSettingEntity from GetSettings method.

```
public static SiteSettingEntity GetSettings<T>(string siteId, Expression<Func<SiteSettingEntity, object>> properties)
    {
        string query = $"SELECT TOP 1 {DbTool.GetSqlFields(properties)} FROM {SiteSettingEntity.TABLE_NAME} (NOLOCK) WHERE Sites.SiteID = @SiteID";

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"SiteID", siteId},
        };

        var _data = DbTool.SqlExec<SiteSettingEntity>(PowerDetailContext.GetConnectionString(siteId), CommandType.Text, query, parameters);

        return _data != null ? _data.FirstOrDefault() : default(SiteSettingEntity);
    }
```